# CircleCI get artifact result page using an Access Token

Tags: ruby, circleci, artifacts

### Context

Using Ruby, I'm trying to get the content of the last artifact that is a result of a **SimpleCov** coverage report.

I'm able so far to retrieve the last artifact with this code (using an Access Token) :

```
module Ci
  class Circle
    # more code

    def artifacts
      @artifacts = self.class.get("/project/github/#{@user}/#{@project}/latest/artifacts?circle-token=#{ENV['CI_ACCESS_TOKEN']}")
      self
    end

    # more code
  end
end
```

Then, I'm retrieving the index page which I want to get the content from, with this code:

```
def report
  artifacts = JSON.parse(@artifacts.parsed_response)
  artifacts.each do |response|
    url = response['url']
    return url if url.end_with? '.html'
  end
  nil
end
```

### Problem

I want to get the content of the coverage page, located at `https://3-57932222-gh.circle-artifacts.com/0//tmp/circle-artifacts.64VZY8w/coverage/index.html`, but when logged out, it shows `Must be log in`. I've tried to check the CircleCI documentation but were not able to find out how to pass an access token to this page in order to get it's content from the command line (where I'm obviously not log in). Ideas?

Comment: i just checked with a project of mine and all urls were reachable without any token.

Comment: Try to access this url `https://3-57932222-gh.circle-artifacts.com/0//tmp/circle-artifacts.64VZY8w/coverage/index.html`. What do you see?

Comment: Ok. I've got `must be log in` but when I have a session open in the browser, I can access that page. I guess I'll try to contact their support in order to find out how to do it. Thanks